# Can not install pkg-config

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I am running ubuntu server 12.04. I want to compile Monetdb on Virtual box, but get error that I have not installed pkg-config. When I use sudo apt-get install pkg-config I get error:

```
Package pkg-config is not available, but is referred to by another package. This mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'pkg-config' has no installation candidate.
```

I did not have this problem on 14.04. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed a problem by:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys KEY
sudo apt-get update
```

Though not sure why it happened.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but just put my findings here in case it will help someone.

In my case, I tried on debian, and the issue is that /etc/apt/sources.list missing one repo. I compared it with a good one and add the missing one and it works.